# Return full document after an Aggregate on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm grouping a Collection on two properties ($user & $game) to return the Document that matches the maximum of $score property

Here's my method:

• Sorting by score descending,
• grouping on (user/game),
• selecting each $first element on each property :

```
db.session.aggregate(
    { $sort: {score: -1} },
    { $group: {
                    _id: { user: "$user", game: "$game"},
                    id: { $first: "$_id"},
                    score: { $first: "$score" }, 
                    user: { $first: "$user" },
                    game: { $first: "$game" },
                    startDate: { $first: "$startDate" },
                    .... & all remaining properties
                }
    },
    { $project: {_id: "$id", score: 1, user: 1, game: 1, startDate: 1, ... } }
)
```

But I'm not satisfied with this since it seems a bit redondant and laborious. If I need one more property in my Collection schema, I'll need to add the property at several places.

I'm sure there is a better method to do this. Any idea?

**EDIT**

My Schema is defined as (in javascript, with `Mongoose`) :

```
var sessionSchema = new Schema({
    user        : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    game        : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Game' },
    level       : Number,
    percent     : Number,
    score       : Number,
    startDate   : Date,
    endDate     : Date,
});
```

There is lots of `User`s and for each `User`, several `Game`s. A `Session` is a `Game` played by a `User` at a given time. So a `User` can have many `Session`s for one `Game`. I just want the `Session` where the player made his hi-score.
Something like :

```
[ {_id: ..., user: u1, game: g1, score: 100, ...},
  {_id: ..., user: u2, game: g1, score: 120, ...},
  {_id: ..., user: u1, game: g2, score: 90, ...},
  ...
]
```

Note I already have something which works. I just wonder if there is something more *elegant*.

Comment: Hard to understand. please documents with expected result.

Comment: You can always use `$$ROOT` if you are trying to save yourself some "typing", but of course that is going to alter the document structure quite a bit and of course does not really meet your objectives for the `$project`. For me I would just do `"doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }` in the grouping and just live with the fact that all fields were under "doc" in the results. Otherwise, saving on "typing" means having a data representation of the schema somewhere else from which you can generate your ideal grouping and projection. You mention schema. Is there one?

Comment: I will try your `$$ROOT` command. Never seen it before :)
Thanks for your feedback

Comment: @BlakesSeven <3 this is exactly what I want, tanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @BlakesSeven, I ended up with the [$$ROOT variable](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) solution.

Since his solution adds an extra descendent in my Document hierarchy, I've decided to flatten the results after querying, with the javascript `map` method.

Here's the complete solution, using `node.js` & `Mongoose`.

```
var query = Session.aggregate();    
query.sort({ score: -1 });
query.group( {
                _id: { user: "$user", quizz: "$quizz"},
                doc: { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
            });
query.project( {_id: 0, doc: 1 } );
query.exec( function(err, results) {
    if (err)
        res.status(500).json({error: err});
    else {
        // flattening the results array
        results = results.map(function(session) {
            return session["doc"];
        });
        res.status(200).json(results);
    }
});
```

Comment: There's another aggregation you can add instead of .map - 
$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" }  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#pipe._S_replaceRoot

Answer (score 5):

A much better option would be to use the **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** pipeline found in MongoDB server versions 3.4 and above. This will promote the embedded **`$$ROOT`** document to the top level and replaces all other fields:

```
var query = Session.aggregate([
    { '$sort': { 'score': -1 } },
    { 
        '$group': {
            '_id': { 'user': '$user', 'quizz': '$quizz' },
            'doc': { '$first': '$$ROOT' }
        }
    },
    { '$replaceRoot': { 'newRoot':  '$doc' } }
]); 

query.exec( function(err, results) {
    if (err)
        res.status(500).json({error: err});
    else {
        res.status(200).json(results);
    }
});
```